Issue sendind an e-mail through a google script
Since Today, I am not able to send an e-mail throught my google script.
Thus I tried a simple script :
function testEmail() {
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: "MyEmail@gmail.com", // e-mail adress to change
subject: "Test d'e-mail",
body: "Ceci est un test pour vérifier l'envoi d'e-mails via Google Apps Script."
});
Logger.log("Test d'e-mail envoyé.");
}

But nothing happens. I don't understand.
I checked quotas and created a new google sheet with a simple function.

This question is similar to: MailApp.sendEmail Not Working?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It worked for me. All I did is used my email

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Perhaps you have another function that is named the same in the same script project? Use console.log() to confirm that the function that runs is the one you think.
